# Activate filtering in maven-remote-resources-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-remote-resources

To share a resource (a properties file) between multiple projects I want to use the `maven-remote-resources-plugin`.
The shared properties file should be filtered by Maven such that the actual program can retrieve some build-information.

Because the properties file is always the same, my goal is to have a parent pom which handles the processing of that file.
The structure of the projects is therefore:

- resource bundle project (contains the properties file)
- parent pom

  - Project 1
  - Project 2
  - ...

Ideally the pom.xml of Project X contains no information about the properties file.

Actually I am really close to my goal.

In the parent pom I added:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.5</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>process-remote-resources</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <resourceBundles>
          <resourceBundle>com.gillesB:resourceJar:1.0</resourceBundle>
        </resourceBundles>
        <runOnlyAtExecutionRoot>true</runOnlyAtExecutionRoot>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I also added the dependency to `com.gillesB:resourceJar:1.0`.

When I build Project X the properties file is written to `target/maven-shared-archive-resources` and it is also added to the generated `jar`.
But the placeholders in the file are not replaced with the actual values.

If I add the following to the Project X pom:

```
<resource>
  <directory>${project.build.directory}/maven-shared-archive-resources</directory>
  <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
```

The properties file in the jar gets filtered.
But to achieve this the child pom must be changed.

As I have not seen `<resource>` in the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/process-mojo.html) and the `process`-goal has its own filter-parameters, I expected that filtering would work out of the box.

### Further Information

I checked the debug logs and it seems that the file is copied twice:

```
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[DEBUG] file app.properties has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] filtering D:\projectX\target\maven-shared-archive-resources\app.properties to D:\projectX\target\classes\app.properties
[DEBUG] resource with targetPath null
directory D:\pX\target\maven-shared-archive-resources
excludes []
includes []
[DEBUG] ignoreDelta true
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[DEBUG] file app.properties has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] copy D:\projectX\target\maven-shared-archive-resources\app.properties to D:\projectX\target\classes\app.properties
[DEBUG] no use filter components
```

If I omit the `<resource>` only the second part appears in the log.
After looking for `no use filter components` the most useful result was the [source code](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/xref/org/apache/maven/plugins/resources/ResourcesMojo.html#L411).
Unfortunately that is not very useful to me.

Comment: did you solve this issue? I have just run into the same problem.